# Node server crashes in parsing JSON

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

Looks like my node server dies in `parseJSON`.
Looked at the logs and the last message was "before parse" and it never printed "after parse". What's strange is that I wrapped JSON.pars with try-catch so I am not sure how it caused the server crashed. Any thoughts?

```
logger.print("before parse")
parseJSON(data)
logger.print("after parse")
```

and I have pareJSON catch exception.

```
function parseJSON(str) {
    try {
        var result = JSON.parse(str);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: You should `use console.error(err)` in `catch` block and see what happened

Comment: what is the `data`?

Comment: JSON.parse is a synchronous method. So if you are planning to parse big JSON objects use a streaming json parser. Maybe use `json-parse-async`.

Comment: data is fairly large string ..

Comment: if I try to parse big json object .. would that cause the server to crash?

Comment: First make sure there's no parsing error, by consoling as @thelonglqd suggested, or check out your data at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: let's say data can be malformed .. but it should never kill the server?

Comment: another page for checking json format: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: my point is even if json format is invalid and JSON.parse failed, it should be handled by "catch" clause ..

Comment: Perhaps if the JSON is gigantic, nodejs might run out of memory and crash without catching any error...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code crashes in parseJSON then I would try:

```
try {
  logger.print("before parse")
  parseJSON(data)
  logger.print("after parse")
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

It is strange because your function should catch the exception but this would show what happens. I would also add:

```
console.log(data.length);
```

to see the size of the data.

Also I wrote a module [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) that parses JSON without throwing exceptions. You can try using it but if your function crashes then maybe my module would not handle it either. Though I'd love to know what actually happens.